# Invoking active_record error - can not load file in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

When I try to run `rails generate scaffold test` the following error always shows

```
C:\Lab\railapps\dbtest>rails generate scaffold test
      invoke  active_record
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': Please install the oracle_enhanced_adapter: `gem install activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter` (cannot load such file -- active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter) (LoadError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'"
```

I did install gem `oci8` then `activerecord-oracle-enhanced-adapter`.
Can you help me by having a look? Thanks a lot.

Version information

```
C:\Lab\railapps\dbtest>gem list ruby-oci8

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

ruby-oci8 (2.1.2 ruby x86-mingw32, 2.0.6)
```

C:\Lab\railapps\dbtest>gem list activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.4.1)
```

database.yml under configure

```
development:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  database: cvrman.cablevision.com
  username: ruby
  password: ruby
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is `activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter` and `oci8` are not in your Gemfile.  Ruby on Rails now uses [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) by default to manage dependencies.

Try adding the lines:

```
   gem "activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter"
   gem "oci8"
```

to your Gemfile (located in the root of your project directory) and run `bundle install`.  Then try building your scaffold.

Comment: This solved the problem. Thank you very much. I added Gemfile adding gem 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter'
gem 'ruby-oci8' 
then run
bundle install
then run 
rails generate scaffold tests -- WORKS!! Thanks